# getting all worksheets data using java

Tags: java, google-sheets-api

I have a google spreadsheet which contains 2 or more worksheets. I am able to print all tabs name or worksheets name using java. I'm looking for a way to print all worksheet data by default it prints only first tab or worksheet. I am attaching my code below plz someone helps me I am pretty new to this [code snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Msk2.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the range first, then return the data in a ValueRange object. See example code below

```
       String range = "UK!A2:E";

        ValueRange response = service.spreadsheets().values()
                .get(spreadsheetId, range)
                .execute();


        List<List<Object>> values = response.getValues();
        if (values == null || values.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("No data found.");
        } else {

            for (List row : values) {

                Iterator<Object> elem = row.iterator();
                while (elem.hasNext()) {
                    System.out.println(elem.next());
                }

            }
        }
```